# Помогите расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Ещё чуть-чуть и больше никогда!

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, контекст, так как непонятно, о чем тут речь. А если это непонятно, то и знаки препинания расставить сложно, причем результат не гарантирует правильность решения..

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от вкладываемого смысла и интонации возможны варианты:

***Ещё чуть-чуть, и больше — никогда!***

***Ещё чуть-чуть — и больше никогда!***

***Ещё чуть-чуть и больше — никогда!***

***Ещё чуть-чуть и больше?  Никогда!***

Answer (score 1):

**Ещё чуть-чуть — и больше никогда!**

Я вижу здесь сложносочиненное предложение (ССП), так что знак препинания перед союзом *и*  необходим. На мой взгляд, наиболее подходящий  знак в данном случае — тире (см. выделенное жирным шрифтом).

[1.2. Знаки препинания в сложносочинённых предложениях:](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/733-12_znaki_prepinaniya_v_slozhnosochinennyh_predlozheniyah.html)

> 4. Вместо запятой простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого предложения могут разделяться тире:
>      Тире ставится в том случае, если во второй части сложносочинённого предложения содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление:
>      Тут раздался лёгкий свист – и Дубровский умолк (Пушкин); Я спешу туда ж – а там уже весь город (Пушкин).
>      **Часто в этих случаях или только первое предложение, или оба предложения являются назывными (номинативными):
>      Ещё напор – и враг бежит (Пушкин); Ещё год, два – и старость... (Эренбург).**